# Running a Aggregate function and then updating that entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

So I have this stored procedure in my **Microsoft SQL Server 2008** Database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateTotalPartID 

@PartID bigint = 1
AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Total int

SELECT @Total = SUM(NoOfItems) FROM dbo.Location WHERE PartID = @PartID;
UPDATE dbo.StockControl
    SET Quantity = @Total
    WHERE PartID = @PartID;
END
GO
```

So instead of using the stored procedure, is there a way that I can just use the `SUM` aggregate function in `DbContext` to update `StockControl.Quantity`, and then do `DbContext.SaveChanges()`?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: `var result = db.YourEntity.Where(o => o.PartID == somePartId).Select(g => new { total = g.Sum(i => i.NoOfItems) });`

You can sum the cost then update your other table with result.

Comment: I could do something like that, but a place in my application I have just a data entry on Locations, where they can enter in the PartID, number of items, etc. but it's not going through the parent entity. I need to update the  parent entity seperately and I was hoping to do that in one shot.

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** - SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems, but it's not a database product. Many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know **what database system** (and which version) you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: It's Entity Frameworks question really, not SQL per se.  I just wanted to know how to use an MS SQL aggregate function in EF

Comment: You may want to add a computed column to `dbo.StockControl`. This will prevent redundancy because the value is computed real-time. It can affect performance though when you fetch large numbers of records.